# chrome and css issue

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, prototypejs

I have this html code

```
<div id = 'status'>
<span class="formw" style="background-color:#FBD9E5;">
some text
</span>
</div>
```

When the following javascript gets executed

```
$('status').style.backgroundColor = '#99e83f';
```

chrome throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

Anybody knows the reason?

Update: I am using Prototype.

Comment: @user ,do we have property called backgroundcolor fordiv, it should be color right or background image url

Comment: I believe you are missing a `#` for the `ID`, do: `$('#status')`, I am assuming you are using jQuery here tho.

Comment: @gov - yes, that property is valid.  @user - does this work with document.getElementById()?

Comment: @steve , you are right , i forgot.

Comment: If it is jQuery, then `.style.foo` is wrong too (and it would be complaining that `style` was null, not that the return value of `$` was. (mutter, mutter, `$` is a hateful variable name: http://blog.dorward.me.uk/2009/02/19/the-dollar-function-must-die.html ). I'd **guess** that `$` was mapped directly on to `document.getElementById` and that the JS was being run before the div appeared in the source code, but the question is missing so much information that that is just poking around blindly.

Answer (score 4):

There are two errors in:

```
$('status').style.backgroundColor = '#99e83f';
```

**First:**

- You are missing the `#` to specify the id in your selector for status div.

**Second:**

- The `style` property won't work on jQuery object that is `$('#status')`.

---

**Solution:**

**Method One:**

```
$('#status')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#99e83f';
```

The `[0]` added above converts jQuery object into normal DOM element so that `style` property is applied successfully.

**Method Two:**

```
('#status').css('background-color','#99e83f');
```

Comment: @sarfraz , i gave your solution some time back , but don't know whether he tried or not.

Comment: @gov: You edited your answer after mine: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4161919/revisions :)

Comment: @sarfraz...hmm i forgot - in between

Comment: @gov: No problem that is what was problem :)

Comment: "The [0] added above converts jQuery object into normal DOM element", thanks, +1.

Comment: @sarfraz: I am using Prototype.

Comment: @user: Then edit your question to include prototype as a tag!

Answer (score 2):

You specifically mention Google Chrome. Chrome is stricter about standards than most, especially if your document has a DOCTYPE.

The markup `<div id = 'status'>` makes me suspicious. Although most browsers are forgiving about common syntax errors it is possible that by having `id` space separated from equals causes it to be treated as a boolean attribute, which is equivalent to `<div id="id">`.

You can test this opening the javascript console (Shift+Ctrl+J) and see what results from typing:

```
$('status')
$('id')
```

For a solution try it like this:

```
<div id="status">
```

*PS. I would guess you don't actually want to alter the DIV's style but the span's, for which any of the following is correct.*

```
$$('#status .formw').style.backgroundColor = '#99e83f';

$$('#status span').style.backgroundColor = '#99e83f';

$('status').down('.formw').style.backgroundColor = '#99e83f';

$('status').select('span').style.backgroundColor = '#99e83f';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#status').style.backgroundColor = '#99e83f';
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not the selector ? I don't get it. Edit : Forget about it, I've just found your comment about this.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery try this

```
$('#status').css('background-color','green');
```

this should work

Comment: @jakub, the rightway of doing in jquery is .css method(syntax) , most of the above answers didn't use that , but why my answer is marked down.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are some DOM hiccups when it comes to elements in prototype when you are using the classic DOM methods.

Instead use the defined methods in prototype to read and set styles for an element.

The two methods you are interested in are:

- .setStyle, documentation( http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/setStyle )
- .getStyle, documentation( http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/getStyle )

So, in example, if you want to set the background of your element, you would use:

```
$('status').setStyle( { 'background-color' : '#99e83f' } );
```

If you wanted to read the attribute, you would use:

```
$('status').getStyle( 'background-color' )
```

For the jquery crowd, the $( 'element_id'  ) is the equivalent shorthand for document.getElementById( 'element_id' ). If you wanted to get the element by selector, it would be $$( '#element_id' ).first().